# Trying to figure out how to print the r in a 2d array

Tags: multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the first element to print out a 'R' instead of a '.'

This is what i have so far then i gave up.

```
    void drawMap(char map[10][10]){
    int i, j;
    printf("Now drawing map\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                    map[i][j] = '.';
                    printf("%c ", map[i][j]);
            }
                    printf("\n");
}
}
```

I can get the dots to print but i have no clue how to make the first element print an R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand truly. You want to print like that

R.........

..........

..........

..........

..........

...

```
  void drawMap(char map[10][10]){
       int i, j;
       printf("Now drawing map\n");
       for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                if(i==0 && j==0)
                   map[i][j] = 'R';
                else
                   map[i][j] = '.';
                printf("%c ", map[i][j]);
          }
                printf("\n");
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the first element of each row to be `R` instead of `.`? When you assign `map[i][j]`, you can select `.` or `R` based on the index of the column you’re assigning, that is, `j`:

```
map[i][j] = j == 0 ? 'R' : '.';
```

This can also be written as an `if` with the `map[i][j]` assignment unfactored:

```
if (j == 0) {
    map[i][j] = 'R';
} else {
    map[i][j] = '.';
}
```

Comment: I added this into my for loops and it printed out! All i changed was in the if statement i put if(j==0 && i==0) Thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated!